# Using for-readline in uwsgi config file doesn't work

Tags: uwsgi

I have a problem with uwsgi config file. I try to set env variables using:

```
for-readline = /home/myuser/envs
  env=%(_)
end-for =
```

cat /home/myuser/envs

```
DATABASE_NAME=some_name
...
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings
REDIS_LOCATION=127.0.0.1:6379:0
```

but it does not work :-( Any idenas?

```
uwsgi --version
1.9.17.1-debian
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for-readline is a >= 2.0.1 option: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Changelog-2.0.1.html